# Assert equal, doesn't start checking in the right folder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, assertions

I'm trying http://www.sitepoint.com/moving-pictures-sinatra-part/ tutorial.

It contains three files:

main.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

def load_pictures
  Dir.glob("public/slideshow_pictures/*.{jpg,JPG}")
end

get '/' do
  @pictures = load_pictures
  @pictures.each do |picture|
    picture
  end
end
```

test/test.rb

```
require_relative '../main'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

class MyTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

    def test_for_echo
      get '/'
      assert last_response.ok?
      assert_equal "slideshow_pictures/test.jpg", last_response.body
    end

    def test_for_pictures
         pictures = load_pictures
         assert pictures.length > 0, "There are no pictures"
    end

end
```

and a public/slideshow_pictures/test.jpg

When I run the test It returns me two errors:

```
  1) Failure:
MyTest#test_for_echo [test.rb:17]:
Expected: "slideshow_pictures/test.jpg"
  Actual: ""


  2) Failure:
MyTest#test_for_pictures [test.rb:22]:
There are no pictures
```

I tried to solve this, and test was passed when I hanged:

```
Dir.glob("public/slideshow_pictures/*.{jpg,JPG}")
```

to:

```
Dir.glob("../public/slideshow_pictures/*.{jpg,JPG}")
```

My question is why does the assertion starts looking in the test folder, not in main folder from which the main.rb file is required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you run you tests inside the `test/` directory.

When using file API, keep in mind what current working directory (`CWD` or `PWD`) is. When referring to relative path, Ruby (or any other language that depend on the underlying file IO) will search files starting at `CWD`.

```
|- main.rb
|- test/
   |- test.rb
```

Given the above directory structure, when you run `main.rb` inside the root directory (using the shell builtin command `cd`), the `CWD` is the root directory. When you are in the root directory, you can run

```
ruby test/test.rb
```

This won't change `CWD`, and your original code should work.

However, if you change to the test directory and run

```
# cd test
ruby test.rb
```

You got your `CWD` as `test/`, and the relative search inside the `main.rb` will fail.

You may construct a path relative to `main.rb` regardless of the `CWD` using:

```
def load_pictures
  path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "public/slideshow_pictures/*.{jpg,JPG}")
  Dir.glob(path)
end
```